# How to place UICollectionView cells on the left/right hand side of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uicollectionview

I have a variety of cells that are dynamically created using an array of Strings that set the UILabel inside each of them. They are each sized based on the intrinsicContentSize() of the particular label. I ensured that the spacing between each cell (horizontally) is enough so that there is only one cell per row. How can I have these cells be placed on the far left hand side/right hand side of the screen instead of centering in the middle? They center because Apple has them do this when there are no other cells on the same 'row'.

Comment: Make the cell the width of the screen and the label go from edge to edge. Then you can set the label contents to justify to the side of the screen you want. I would make prototype cells in storyboard the sizes and properties you want and then call them by identifier in your code.

Comment: are you using auto layout or normal frames?

Comment: @Zhang I did most of this programmatically (in swift) so no, there is only autolayout applied to the contents inside a cell cause I set some constraints for the label in storyboard.

Comment: @timquinn "Then you can set the label contents to justify to the side of the screen you want' confuses me, are you describing what to do with the storyboard? The label size depends on what the user writes in a textView so it is not set prior to runtime.

Comment: I am suggesting that you use a collectionViewCell prototype in storyboard and have the cell fill the horizontal space in the view and the label the allowable space, i.e. between the blue lines. Why do you need the label to be size to fit if it is giving you issues? If the label fills the horizontal space then you can slide the contents to the edge of the screen you want using the textAlignment property of the label.